# Jackson XML Annotations: String element with attribute

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I can't seem to find a way to make a Pojo Using the jackson-xml annotations that would generate xml like the following:

```
<Root>
    <Element1 ns="xxx">
        <Element2 ns="yyy">A String</Element2>
    </Element1>
</Root>
```

The closest I can seem to come is the following:

**Root POJO**:

```
public class Root {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Element1")
    private Element1 element1;

    public String getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }

    public void setElement1(String element1) {
        this.element1 = element1;
    }
}
```

**Element1 POJO**:

```
public class Element1 {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String ns = "xxx";
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Element2")
    private Element2 element2;

    public String getElement2() {
        return element2;
    }

    public void setElement2(String element2) {
        this.element2 = element2;
    }
}
```

**Element2 POJO**:

```
public class Element2 {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String ns = "yyy";
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

But this returns back the following:

```
<Root>
    <Element1 ns="xxx">
        <Element2 ns="yyy"><value>A String</value></Element2>
    </Element1>
</Root>
```

The element tags around "A String" I do not want to display.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're using Jackson-specific annotations and not JAXB annotations. Jackson is primarily a framework for producing JSON, not XML, and as such, misses some of the features of JAXB.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You should use [JacksonXmlText](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlText.html) annotation for `value` field.

```
public class Element2 
{
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String ns = "yyy";
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

then XML will looks like

```
<Root>
    <Element1 ns="xxx">
        <Element2 ns="yyy">A String</Element2>
    </Element1>
</Root>
```

Comment: Turns out I was importing from the wrong dependency, and getting and older version of the jackson-dataformat-xml where that annotation wasn't included :\

Comment: Understandable. As fantastic as Jackson is, their documentation is horrendous. So it is very hard to find which versions are where and which annotations are available with those versions.

Comment: I've definitely dug through their documentation before, and I know what you mean, but this one is definitely on me - Their dependency is blatantly mentioned on their github page: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml. I was looking for the gradle dependency, and googled & pasted too fast.

Comment: @llya : Do we not need `@JacksonXmlRootElement` on `Root` class ?

Comment: Awesome when someone provides EXACTLY what you were looking for.  +1

Answer (score 5):

To complement [flyingAssistant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66223059/3208393), you can't add @JacksonXmlText to a constructor property. This feature may be added in build 2.13 based off of this [issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/423#issue-694858880) reported in the GitHub repository.
So for now you'll have to do this

```
data class Element2(@field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true) val ns: String = "yyy") {
    @field:JacksonXmlText
    val value: String? = null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin, you need to use `@field` [annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) use-site targets:

```
data class Element2(
        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        val ns: String = "yyy",
        @field:JacksonXmlText
        val value: String? = null
)
```

If you don't like defining initial values for `ns` and `value` properties by yourself then use [Kotlin no-args plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html), which generates a default constructor instead.