# Unmarshal xml property with both attribute values and subelements

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm using Jackson (jackson-dataformat-xml, v2.13.0) to map an XML string into a corresponding Kotlin object. The XML looks like this:

```
<tide>
    <service cominfo="Some text..."/>
    <locationdata>
        <location name="Oslo" code="OSL" latitude="59.904794"
              longitude="10.753642" delay="0" factor="1.00" obsname="Oslo"
              obscode="OSL" descr="Tidevann fra Oslo"/>
        <reflevelcode>CD</reflevelcode>
        <data type="prediction" unit="cm">
            <waterlevel value="88.5" time="2021-10-22T06:50:00+01:00" flag="high"/>
            <waterlevel value="69.8" time="2021-10-22T11:53:00+01:00" flag="low"/>
            <waterlevel value="95.1" time="2021-10-22T19:05:00+01:00" flag="high"/>
        </data>
    </locationdata>
</tide>
```

I'm having a hard time extracting whatever is inside the *data* field, because it contains both attribute values (*type* and *unit*) as well as a list of *waterlevel*.

In my controller, I'm doing a simple mapping:

```
val mapper: ObjectMapper = XmlMapper.builder()
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES)
            .build()
val tide: Tide = mapper.readValue(tideLevels, Tide::class.java)
```

I am unable to get everything from the **data** tag. It seems to me as if I have to choose between attributes and sub elements. The following mapping:

```
data class Tide(
    val service: TideServiceInfo? = null,
    val locationdata: LocationData? = null
)

data class LocationData(
    val location: Location? = null,
    val reflevelcode: String = "",
    val data: TideData? = null
)

data class TideData(
    val type: String = "",
    val unit: String = "",
    val waterlevel: List<WaterLevel> = emptyList()
)

data class WaterLevel(
    val value: String = "",
    val time: String = "",
    val flag: String = ""
)
```

Gives me resulting json with an empty waterlevel-array:

```
{
    "service": {
        "cominfo": "Some text..."
    },
    "locationdata": {
        "location": {shortened for brevity},
        "reflevelcode": "CD",
        "data": {
            "type": "prediction",
            "unit": "cm",
            "waterlevel": []
        }
    }
}
```

But if I instead choose to map to the following data classes:

```
data class Tide(
    val service: TideServiceInfo? = null,
    val locationdata: LocationData? = null
)

data class LocationData(
    val location: Location? = null,
    val reflevelcode: String = "",
    val data: List<WaterLevel> = emptyList()
)

data class WaterLevel(
    val value: String = "",
    val time: String = "",
    val flag: String = ""
)
```

My result json has the data field set, without *type* and *unit*:

```
{
    "service": {
        "cominfo": "Some text..."
    },
    "locationdata": {
        "location": { shortened for brevity },
        "reflevelcode": "CD",
        "data": [
            {
                "value": "88.5",
                "time": "2021-10-22T06:50:00+01:00",
                "flag": "high"
            },
            {
                "value": "69.8",
                "time": "2021-10-22T11:53:00+01:00",
                "flag": "low"
            },
            {
                "value": "95.1",
                "time": "2021-10-22T19:05:00+01:00",
                "flag": "high"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried looking into annotations to put on data fields, e.g. *@JacksonXmlProperty*, but I don't see how that can help me achieve my solution.
Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
@field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
```

to your attribute fields. See the [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html) for more info.

Note that you need `@field` in Kotlin to apply the annotation to the actual object field

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get that much out of the docs. I assume you mean something like this:
```data class LocationData(
    val location: Location? = null,
    val reflevelcode: String = "",
    val data: TideData? = null
)

data class TideData(
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    val type: String = "",
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    val unit: String = "",
    val waterlevel: List<WaterLevel> = emptyList()
)
waterlevel as before, need to save chars.
```
But it still doesn't work. Should *data* be of type **TideData** or an array?

Comment: See this answer for an example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847094/jackson-xml-annotations-string-element-with-attribute

You should do the similar thing, `    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    val type: String
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "waterLevel")
    val data: List<WaterLevel>`

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions from @Evgeny did not work for me, but it did lead me on the right path searching on.
Basically, the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65353534/3432964), introducing the `useWrapping=false` is what turned out to do the trick.

So I got what I wanted using the following:

```
@field:JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    val waterlevel: List<WaterLevel> = emptyList()
```