# How to parse this XML with Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jackson, jaxb

I have an XML document that I want to parse using Jackson XML:

```
<one>
  <two id="X"></two>
  <two>Text</two>
</one>
```

I made these data classes to contain the data:

```
data class One(val two: List<Two>)
data class Two(val id: String)
```

These work for the first `two` element, but not for the next one.

I tried adding a `@JacksonXmlText`-annotated field to the `Two` class, but that doesn't help: It'll try to parse a sub-tag containing text, not the text in the element. And I can't use `@JacksonXmlText` on a `two` field in `One`, since that won't allow me to also parse the attributes.

How do I parse this XML document?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69749546/unmarshal-xml-property-with-both-attribute-values-and-subelements ?

Comment: Not the same. This is specifically about the *text* in the element, and the solution in the question `(isAttribute=true)` does not work here.